# iTextSharp offsetting image

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am generating a byte array image and in order to convert it to pdf I am adding that image into a PDF document. the image size is exactly 812, 1015 DPI and even though I have document with the same size the image is being offset by about an inch (the red bar represents this offset) because of this I am missing about the same amount on the other side. Why is the PDF adding the image in this way. Here is the code:

```
var resizedImage = new Bitmap(812, 1015);
var drawResizedImage = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImage);
drawResizedImage.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, 812, 1015);

resizedImage.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
return getPDFDocument(memoryStream);

private byte[] getPDFDocument(MemoryStream inputImageStream)
{
    MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
    iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(812, 1015));
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, workStream).CloseStream = false;

    document.Open();
    iTextSharp.text.Image pdfImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(inputImageStream.ToArray());
    document.Add(pdfImage);
    document.Close();

    byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
    workStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
    workStream.Position = 0;

    return workStream.ToArray();
}
```

This is producing this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your code block

> pdfImage.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);

You should see this:

```
document.Open();
iTextSharp.text.Image pdfImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(inputImageStream.ToArray());
pdfImage.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
document.Add(pdfImage);
document.Close();
```

That should give you the desired positioning.